# Google Maps API error pop up windows

Tags: javascript, google-api-php-client

I have Google Maps API error which I am aware there is similar question asked before. I had PHP page with map canvas which was working in previous domain before June 2016. I bought new domain that made trouble. I fix it by reading article at http://www.mochasupport.com/kayako/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=710 and also articles fro stackoverflow. I made the changes and the web site back to work with key. Now the problem is on same page that have the main map when I am trying to open pop up window with map, still have the same famous error. On js console same key that I am using on main page child page not reads the key. How it can be solve?

Comment: assuming the popup has the same domain as the main page, or at least a domain that is "registered" with the key, the problem is somewhere in your code - line 37 is  my guess

Comment: yes, pop up has the same domain. also the ggogleapis have key generated for http page with all options of domain name.